# Unable to Establish a linked server connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am facing issues establishing a linked server connection from SQL Server 2022 Standard Edition to SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. Despite having an open 1433 port, a functional SQL to SQL connection, appropriate user permissions, and a firewall that is configured correctly, I am still unable to establish the connection.

[image: Error Message showing while configuring the linked server]

- Checked Telnet
- Checked ping
- Checked the user name and password
- Checked SQL to SQL connection
- Checked 1433 port
- Checked firewall
- Checked the TCP/IP and Named pipes in the configuration manager

All the above seems ok

Comment: You should revisit the `Checked the user name and password`. And the fact that you are connecting to the right server.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-sql-server-error-18456-in-simple-ways) could help you.

Comment: check sql server log of the target server to see if there are any details that can share some light on the issue. do you use "be made using security context"-setting for the linked server, or use context login? Note that you usually cannot make windows authentication logins work by typing DOMAIN\user in the above box

Comment: If you have access to the machine hosting the SQL Server Express instance, have you opened SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager there and checked the Server Protocols configuration for the **SQLEXPRESS** instance? Does it have the TCP/IP protocol enabled? Inside the TCP/IP protocol settings what port(s) does it have enabled and active? (Hint: for SQL Express it's almost never port 1433.)

Comment: Error 18456 is typically a login failure message from the server, so if your SQL Express instance is actually listening on port 1433 (unlikely), have you checked its Error Logs for the error 18456 messages? Take note of the `State` numbers that they report and compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual cause of the login failure.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I updated the Linked Server to "local IP address" of the SQL Server 2012 and changed the server type to "SQL Server". The Linked Server is now functioning properly. Thank you.